# How can I execute remote MySQL queries via shell script without putting open text password in my shell script?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, my.cnf

I'd rather not execute a query in a shell script with an open text password.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uuser -hremotehost -pmypassword -e "update my_table set what_time = NOW()";
```

Is there a way to put `mypassword` in my local `/etc/my.cnf` file or something else to keep it out of open text command line?

Assume my `remotehost` doesn't accept no password for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written over at [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/is-it-possible-to-have-passwords-configured-per-database-or-per-host-in-my-cnf) it is possible to configure your `my.cnf` file as the following:

```
[clienthost1]   # Note: client + host1
user=user
password=mypassword
host=remotehost
```

and run it as:

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=host1
```

Kudus to [Derek Downey answer at DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/is-it-possible-to-have-passwords-configured-per-database-or-per-host-in-my-cnf)

Comment: Interesting. Is `host1` configurable? For example, can I use `clientmy_host_name`? And then run `mysql --defaults-group-suffix=my_host_name`?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER

Create `~/.my.cnf` file and put the following into it:

```
[foo]
user=user
password=mypassword
host=remotehost

[bar]
user=user2
password=some-other-password
host=127.0.0.1
```

Then invoke `mysql --login-path=foo ...` to connect to `remotehost` or `mysql --login-path=bar ...` for local host.

Comment: does that work with a remote host as well? What if I have a local mysql instance and a remote mysql instance?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) and store the data in an encrypted file.

Example:

```
mysql_config_editor set --user=user --password --host=remotehost
Enter password:
```